# How would I build a civilisation of multiple worlds around multiple suns work?

Tags: magic, physics, biology

I’m building a group of magical civilisations, in which there are seven suns, orbiting a much larger sun, each with their own planets. There are forty planets in total. Some are moons orbiting gas giants. The civilisation was built as a kind of zoo by a now departed alien race, and humans were one of a dozen alien species deposited here, so it's possible for all the worlds to have been engineered to have relatively similar gravity and year-length, compared to Earth. There’s a kind of hyperspace dimension next door which humans can burrow through to transport themselves.

I’d like to get the physics of this right, and I’m wondering what I need to take into account. So:

1. What factors that I’ve forgotten could potentially have made this civilisation uninhabitable for humans? What would the alien designers have needed to correct for?
2. How far apart would the suns need to be to avoid dragging one another out of orbit? How long would it take to communicate between them? What level of technology would you need to observe, communicate and travel between: 
   a) worlds orbiting the same gas giant 
   b) worlds orbiting the same sun 
   c) worlds orbiting a co-orbiting sun
3. How cold would the central star need to be? Would it make sense for the inner sun to be a black hole?

Comment: Since it is artificial you can use Klemperer rosettes. You can have all seven suns orbit their common barycenter on the same orbit and each of the suns have seven planets sharing the same orbit. Simplest possible solution. Rosettes are not stable but if the aliens place the zoo far enough from other stellar objects and the system does not have anything extra causing asymmetry and the aliens left some sort of automated maintenance system at the center... Why not, any technology that can make it can keep it stable easy enough.

Comment: The question could use a little rework: several questions not dependant of each other and title is a bit confusing.

Comment: This question was automatically locked when it was put on hold because of the migration, which prevented edits.  Sorry about that -- I've unlocked it now, so you can [edit] to address comments.